# How to Confirm or Enable LDAP/SSL for Azure AD Connect?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, microsoft-office-365, office365, azureadconnect

Microsoft has an advisory that states they will be prepping LDAP/SSL (LDAPS). https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV190023

While Microsoft doesnt specifically list instructions to setup LDAP/SSL for Azure AD Connect, there is reference to LDAP/SSL (LDAPS) being used in article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-ports

- Is there a way to verify if Azure AD Connect is already using
  LDAP/SSL?
- Is there a way to configure Azure AD Connect to only use
  LDAP/SSL?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled across your post looking for the same information. I think it's as below but yet to test.

Under Synchronisation Service Manager > Connectors select your domain connector > Properties. Under "Connect to Active Directory Forest" you have an options button, untick "Sign & Encrypt LDAP traffic" and select "Enable SSL for the Connection".

Comment: Thank you-- this sounds promising. Were there any articles that referenced that setting? Once I'm able to test I'll update the status.

Comment: I took it from Tip 2 here https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/11/03/generic-ldap-connector-for-azure-ad-connect/ This is all I could find other than the articles you mentioned.

Comment: Do I need to reenter the password for this connector-- when I try it I get an error: "An error was encountered trying to retrieve the SSL cipher strength"

Comment: Hmm.. do I need the forest name to point to the FQDN of the server instead of only the domain name. i.e. server.domain.local instead of domain.local?

Comment: nope, that didn't work.

Comment: LDP.exe shows :`Host supports SSL, SSL cipher strength = 256 bits`

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else is struggling... I faced the same problem and got the error message "An error was encountered trying to retrieve the SSL cipher strength" when trying to enable LDAP via SSL.

I had to change the settings under "Synchronisation Service Manager > Connectors select your domain connector > Properties". Under "Configure Directory Partitions" you have an options button next to "Configure Connection Security", untick "Sign & Encrypt LDAP traffic" and select "Enable SSL for the Connection" (+Enable CRL Checking, which should be obviously yes if you are using cert based authentication :-).

Wireshark confirmed the setting and my traffic is now encrypted via TLSv1.2 between Azure AD Connect Server and the DC.